# Any problem with burninating [problem-user] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

The [problem-user](/questions/tagged/problem-user) tag has 12 questions for now, and I don't think it's a proper tag. It has no tag wiki.

In some cases it's just useless, in others can be replaced with [users](/questions/tagged/users) tag and perhaps adding [abuse](/questions/tagged/abuse) tag if it's about users abusing the system.

Thoughts? Objections? Please don't go and burninate right away, let's give people time to post their objection, e.g. at least a full day.

Comment: I vote for burning it. It is too generic to be useful IMHO. Maybe a more specific alternative is also [tag:specific-user], but calling out single users is discouraged anyway.

Comment: @MEE yes, the only valid use of [tag:specific-user] tag is for cases where only one user is bugged, which are very rare.

Comment: *tempted to tag this problem-user*

Comment: Let's get rid of all these [problem-user]s

Answer (score 6):

I agree with your reasoning that the tag is not needed, but I feel that a major reason to go ahead and do it now is that using the tag is not nice. We have:

- a [spam](/questions/tagged/spam) tag but not a [spammer](/questions/tagged/spammer) tag
- a [serial-voting](/questions/tagged/serial-voting) tag but not a [serial-voter](/questions/tagged/serial-voter) tag
- an [offensive](/questions/tagged/offensive) tag but not an [offender](/questions/tagged/offender) tag
- a [copyright-infringement](/questions/tagged/copyright-infringement) tag but not a [copyright-infringer](/questions/tagged/copyright-infringer) tag
- an [abuse](/questions/tagged/abuse) tag but not an [abuser](/questions/tagged/abuser) tag
- a [review-abuse](/questions/tagged/review-abuse) tag but not a [review-abuser](/questions/tagged/review-abuser) tag
- a [legal](/questions/tagged/legal) tag but not a [lawbreaker](/questions/tagged/lawbreaker) tag
- a [hacked](/questions/tagged/hacked) tag but not a [haxor](/questions/tagged/haxor) tag

This is a generalization of the practice known as [Person-first language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People-first_language), which is widely accepted as polite. Label the behavior we want to eliminate, not the person with the problem. There's no reason to have [problem-user](/questions/tagged/problem-user) as an exception. If [users](/questions/tagged/users) and [abuse](/questions/tagged/abuse) are not enough, you can tag [behavior](/questions/tagged/behavior), [code-of-conduct](/questions/tagged/code-of-conduct), [terms-of-service](/questions/tagged/terms-of-service), or by the specific kind of inappropriate behavior (e.g. [spam](/questions/tagged/spam), [copyright-infringement](/questions/tagged/copyright-infringement), or [serial-voting](/questions/tagged/serial-voting)).