# Remove (again) and prevent creation of the specific-user tag

Tags: discussion, meta, burninate-request, tag-block-request, specific-user-tag

From the accepted answer at [Should any Meta post that calls out a user by name be deleted, not just downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289909) :

> There's a reason we always kill off the [specific-user](/questions/tagged/specific-user) tag every time it appears.

However, it seems this doesn't actually happen. As of now [I see](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-user) two questions thus tagged, one of which is from all the way back in 2011.

Shouldn't the tag simply be blocked, so that such "killing off" is not required? The system also currently allows me to type such a tag in the list on this question, and it will appear as a tag (of course, I am not submitting the post with that tag).

Comment: @Shog9 : Do we need [tag:specific-user-tag]? It almost has been one month since it was created, it still has no wiki and still has only one question. Could you please add the tag excerpt?

Comment: Related : [Any problem with burninating \[problem-user\] tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328757/289691)

Comment: If there are no more questions on the topic in a few months, it should be automatically removed @ruben. Tags should generally be self-managing.

Comment: I'm asking just in case you have something in mind that you missed to share. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 9):

I've removed it for now

I think part of the issue is that clearing out a tag is a lot less 'work' than the formal tag blocklisting process. Better tooling to do this might be handy and I'll check up and bring it up via the appropriate channels at some point if we haven't already

Comment: Isn't there a way to just, well, add a tag to blocklist?

Comment: Get a CM to do it generally. Which dosen't scale

Comment: That may not "scale", but how often do we actually encounter tags requiring such treatment?

Comment: Surprisingly often. And it takes no time at all to do a request and clear.

Comment: Technically, CMs can't actually do tag blocks at the moment. We need a dev. We have a long-standing request to add UI for CMs that won't allow us to break things because we're not regex experts... and that's actually seeing some movement but it's not quite next up for prioritization.

Comment: Well,  We'd need to ping a CM to ping a dev to...   or do it ourselves when needed. Its not a few hundred posts or anything :D